# Essentially nonEuclidean space?

Tags: geometry

As far as I know, all the objects of interest in differential geometry are at least locally Euclidean; I mean that they are somewhat analogous to being 'linearly approximable.'  An ant on the manifold will think it resides on the Euclidean space. Then, as there exist essentially nonlinear systems in the nature(which are not linearly approximable), are there some topological spaces that are of physical interest but essentially not Euclidean? My question is rather vague, because I only have a vague feeling of what I am really curious about. Anyway, are there some nontrivial, physically meaningful space that is never approximable by Euclidean space? I am just curious...